# user quota value deleted on reboot

Tags: debian, users, quota

I´ve activated user quota on Debian 9. I´ve set a quota by command

```
edquota -u testuser
```

I´ve set a value for soft (20000000) and hard (20100000) and saved the file. 
`repquota -a` shows the newly entered values for testuser.

After rebooting the system the soft and hard values are reset to 0 for the testuser. What could be the reason for?

Comment: Do you have the file `/aquota.user` ? Is it writable?

Comment: No, there´s no such file, but on other systems, where it works, there´s also no such file.